What is the impact of Pruning on transaction integrity?
In the scenario of 100% of Bitcoin Core nodes having been 'pruned', what is the impact on syncing new installs of Bitcoin Core. Can Bitcoin Core still download the entire transaction history as required, and if yes, how? If not, what is the impact on securing future integrity of transactions if less and less active nodes are on the system as a result of pruning and being unable to download the entire blockchain history.
Background: I have always run a full node for years, but am not always 'live'. I recently had upgraded to Bitcoin Core 27 and it immediately got stuck. I tried for several days, no change. Then I was forced to go back to Bitcoin Core 25. It has processed the chain up to Fri Feb 9 09:32:36 2024 and has been stuck at Progress 90.60% for nearly a day, with 1 Peer connected. To say the least, this is concerning. I never experienced any issues bringing the chain up to date until pruning was introduced, and I am concerned that pruning is becoming so widespread that the necessary blockchain download can no longer be reliably performed. And if that is the case, how is integrity being maintained if new nodes cannot be onboarded and active nodes are in decline?

It might be better if you ask about the Bitcoin App in a new question, since that seems a cleanly separable topic.

If there were only pruned nodes, no new nodes can synchronize the blockchain from the network. People could still copy the data directory of pruned nodes, but they would trust whoever is offering the data.
Luckily, this scenario is not reality: Bitnodes is currently reporting reporting about 19k listening nodes that offer the NODE_NETWORK peer service, which means that they serve the complete blockchain. It sounds like you may be misattributing the issue you experienced.
Did something about your network change, e.g. are you now behind a firewall? What hardware is your node running on? How did you go about upgrading to Bitcoin Core 27.0.? How long did you try running v27.0 before downgrading to Bitcoin Core 25.0?

Your machine’s specs seem fine. Bitcoin.org should be fine as a source of the software, although Bitcoin Core’s project site would be bitcoincore.org. Let’s take a look at the log messages:

"UpdateTip":
That’s the good stuff. Your node processed a block and extended the
chain. It’s making progress on synchronizing.
"Cache size (771532064) exceeds total space (761373440)":
Whenever you process blocks, your node has to load existing coins
from disk to see that the money transactions are spending exist.
These Unspent Transaction Outputs (UTXOs) get stored in your cache.
When the cache is full, the node writes is back to disk. In your log
it says "Config file: F:\BitcoinCore\bitcoin.conf (not found,
skipping)", so I guess that you are running with the default
configuration which is very conservative in its resource use. Since
your machine has 32 GB of RAM, you should be able to significantly
speed up your synchronization by increasing the permitted cache by
setting dbcache=4000. You can do this in the configuration file,
startup options, or probably also in the settings from the graphical
interface somewhere. 4000 would correspond to 4 GB, I think the
default is 500 MB. This will lead to your node using a bit more RAM
to read and write a lot less often to disk. There were also some
improvements in the caching behavior for synchronization in Bitcoin
Core 28, so you might find that it is a bit faster if you try that.
Bitcoin.org may not have had it yet, but it is available on
bitcoincore.org.
"Peer=19 is stalling block download"
That one seems to be the real crux of the issue. What you describe reminds me of the issue described by dooglus here. It seems that your node somehow got itself into a situation where it is cycling its peers. It’s missing one or a few blocks, because it did have a slow peer, but got a bunch of other blocks after that from other peers, now in order to fill the gap, it requires any new peer on connection to give your node that block within two seconds. This might especially be an issue if your internet connection is not particularly fast, or the block you are missing is bigger than usual. I’m not 100% sure whether this behavior still exists in recent releases, I think there was some work on it, but it might not be fixed yet. Again, it might be resolved by trying to use Bitcoin Core v28.0. Otherwise, you might be able to resolve this issue by temporarily restricting your node to a single peer, in order to remove the comparison between peers by setting maxconnections: 1. While that will slow down the expected synchronization speed, it should get rid of the peer stalling behavior. After it fills the gap, you should disable it again, so your node can get information from multiple peers and sync faster.


Thank you for your answer.
"If there were only pruned nodes, no new nodes can synchronize the blockchain from the network. People could still copy the data directory of pruned nodes, but they would trust whoever is offering the data."
I am not that tech savvy. I was under the impression that a Bitcoin Core install requires the full blockchain first. I will have to find out more about this.

"Luckily, this scenario is not reality: Bitnodes is currently reporting reporting about 19k listening nodes that offer the NODE_NETWORK peer service, which means that they serve the complete blockchain."
Thank you for that link. I was going by https://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/services.html which shows only about 4000 full nodes active.
"It sounds like you may be misattributing the issue you experienced."
Possible. I had some issues with my PC and had to do a clean re-install of Windows 10 which then affected the software registry due to changes in drives.

"Did something about your network change, e.g. are you now behind a firewall?"
The only thing I can think of is that the Win 10 firewall changed. However, the firewall is managed by Avast. I have exempted Bitcoin Core as well as opened port 8333 for in and out traffic.
"What hardware is your node running on? How did you go about upgrading to Bitcoin Core 27.0.?"
Win 10 Home x64-based PC Processor AMD FX-8320E Eight-Core Processor, 3200 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) 970A-DS3P 32GB RAM

"How did you go about upgrading to Bitcoin Core 27.0.?"
Downloaded from Bitcoin.org and ran the installer pointing to the relevant directories.
"How long did you try running v27.0 before downgrading to Bitcoin Core 25.0?"
About 36 hours, and it didn't even grab a single block. Since I posted my original comment, Bitcoin Core has intermittent peer connection and has advanced to Mar 24

Could you take a look at the debug.log in your Bitcoin directory, whether you see anything that could help us troubleshoot this?

2024-12-13T19:46:47Z Peer=19 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2024-12-13T19:46:48Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874609, peer=139
2024-12-13T19:46:59Z Peer=132 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2024-12-13T19:47:47Z Peer=38 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2024-12-13T20:23:58Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874611, peer=189
2024-12-13T20:27:52Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874611, peer=191

2024-12-13T20:58:56Z Cache size (771532064) exceeds total space (761373440)
2024-12-13T21:29:05Z Peer=237 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2024-12-13T21:30:59Z New block-relay-only v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874623, peer=251
2024-12-13T21:31:05Z Peer=246 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2024-12-13T21:49:57Z Disconnecting outbound peer 231 for old chain, best known block = 
2024-12-13T21:51:30Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874624, peer=284
2024-12-13T21:52:08Z Peer=251 is stalling block download, disconnecting

2024-12-13T21:57:28Z Cache size (776301152) exceeds total space (761373440)
2024-12-13T22:09:06Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874626, peer=308
2024-12-13T22:09:12Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=874626, peer=309
2024-12-13T22:12:25Z Peer=308 is stalling block download, disconnecting
[Cache size exceeds total space is a recurring theme. Any suggestion how I can fix that?]
2024-12-13T23:08:52Z Disconnecting outbound peer 362 for old chain, best known block = 

Suddenly on 12-14 I get a rush of new "GUI: OpenType support missing" messages
2024-12-14T03:29:29Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "MS Shell Dlg 2", script 12
2024-12-14T03:29:29Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "Arial", script 12
2024-12-14T03:29:29Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "MS UI Gothic", script 12
2024-12-14T03:29:29Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "SimSun", script 12
2024-12-14T03:29:29Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "MS Shell Dlg 2", script 14
2024-12-14T03:29:29Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "Arial", script 14
and so on

I am sorry, I how I don't break some etiquette here. I don't know if there's a better way.
2024-12-14T15:29:12Z Bitcoin Core version v27.0.0 (release build)
2024-12-14T15:29:15Z Config file: F:\BitcoinCore\bitcoin.conf (not found, skipping)
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z initload thread start
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z Loading 0 mempool transactions from disk...
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z Imported mempool transactions from disk: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 expired, 0 already there, 0 waiting for initial broadcast
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z initload thread exit

2024-12-14T15:29:52Z Bound to 127.0.0.1:8334
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z Bound to [::]:8333
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z Bound to 0.0.0.0:8333
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z Loaded 0 addresses from "anchors.dat"
2024-12-14T15:29:52Z 0 block-relay-only anchors will be tried for connections.
2024-12-14T15:31:42Z P2P peers available. Skipped DNS seeding.
2024-12-14T15:31:42Z dnsseed thread exit
2024-12-14T16:11:50Z Peer=59 is stalling block download, disconnecting
2024-12-14T16:12:12Z Peer=26 is stalling block download, disconnecting

Then a bunch of these type...
2024-12-15T18:44:50Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "MS Shell Dlg 2", script 12
2024-12-15T18:59:05Z mapport thread start
2024-12-15T18:59:05Z natpmp: initnatpmp() failed with -8 error.

Then a bunch of these type...
2024-12-15T18:44:50Z GUI:   OpenType support missing for "MS Shell Dlg 2", script 12
2024-12-15T18:59:05Z mapport thread start
2024-12-15T18:59:05Z natpmp: initnatpmp() failed with -8 error.
...and this last new error starts repeating quite frequently
2024-12-15T21:24:08Z Cache size (806868416) exceeds total space (761373440)
every ~5 minutes now...
2024-12-16T14:34:02Z natpmp: initnatpmp() failed with -8 error.
new error message...
2024-12-16T18:19:02Z natpmp: readnatpmpresponseorretry() for public address failed with -5 error.
[repeating]

I gave up on 2024-12-17
2024-12-17T16:05:26Z Bitcoin Core version v25.0.0 (release build)
still getting...
2024-12-17T16:14:45Z natpmp: initnatpmp() failed with -8 error.
2024-12-18T04:27:46Z Cache size (761925232) exceeds total space (761373440)
These two seem to be the persistent errors. Anything I can do to resolve these?

Hi Jared, you can edit your question post to add more information to it. I think the two errors give us a couple hints. I will respond to them in my answer post.

Thank you Murch for both answering my questions and concerns, as well as providing solutions. I am a senior citizen and things are not as simple anymore as they used to be. It appears that the issues with the clients have been resolved as it is now sitting at a healthy progress rate. Again, thank you very much for your time and efforts on addressing my post.

Woohoo, thanks for letting me know, I’m glad it worked!
